# Javascript causing error to emailsender.php

Tags: javascript, php

I have this javascript code to do not redirect when user press submit after fill form inputs. The problem is: When I use this javascript my emailsender.php just don't work and I don't know why.

```
    var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function() {
            form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Enviando E-mail...</p>').fadeIn());
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">E-mail enviado com sucesso</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

I'm using phpmailer

EDIT:
emailsender.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){ 
        require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
        require_once 'class.smtp.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $nome       = $_POST['username'];
        $email      = $_POST['useremail'];
        $texto      = $_POST['usermessage'];
        $corpo = "<strong>Nome:</strong> $nome<br /><strong>E-mail:</strong> $email<br /><strong>Mensagem:</strong><br /><br />$texto";
        $mail->Host = 'mail.XXXXXXX.com.br';
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->Username = 'contato@XXXXXXX.com.br';
        $mail->Password = 'XXXXXXX';
        $mail->From = $email;
        $mail->FromName = $nome;
        $mail->Subject = 'XXXXXXX';
        $mail->AddAddress('contato@XXXXXXX.com.br');
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $corpo;
        if ($mail->Send()) {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }
?>
```

html form:

```
<form action="sendemail" id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post">
    <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" id="useremail" name="useremail" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="usermessage" id="usermessage" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Mensagem" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please show emailsender.php.

Comment: What is the value of $(this).attr('action')? Be aware that `this` may change scope inside the ajax call.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez, I posted in main post.

Comment: @Wash Basically when press submit it should only send data to .php but it's causing any problem that I can't get

Comment: You miss **'** in this part `$mail->Subject = 'XXXXXXX;`

Comment: @jameshwartlopez It's ok in my script, I just changed values here in forum, sorry

Comment: Plese post also the html form

Comment: @jameshwartlopez done

Comment: I should have noticed that you forgot to pass **`data`** and **`type`** post in your ajax  request . [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804278/javascript-causing-error-to-emailsender-php?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: `<form action="sendemail.php"`  please add the file extension there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass data and type in your ajax code.

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
           form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Enviando E-mail...</p>').fadeIn());
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">E-mail enviado com sucesso</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Please also change your `<form action="emailsender.php"`

Note that this will never be true since your are using ajax

`if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST))`,Your other option is check the other keys.

sample

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['useremail'] && isset($_POST['usermessage']))){
   //YOUR SEND EMAIL CODE
}
```

Comment: My big fault but It is not working too :/
Already cleaned cache.

Comment: have you check developers console?if there is an error in your javascript?

Comment: No errors this is my site criacaodesitesbh.pampulhatech.com.br... the form is at the end of the page

Comment: your form action attribute does not point to `emailsender.php`

Comment: Its sendemail.php but I'm using mod_rewrite. Already tried to change this javascript and already added .php at .html but still doesn't work